# PHP memcached wont connect but no error in log files or on screen

Tags: php, codeigniter, memcached

I cant not get codeigniter to speak to my external memcached server. I'm running memcached with the -vvv flag, when using memcached via php normally, it works fine (thank you zerkms). But when i try to set/get values via codeigniter, it does not even connect to the remove server, but i get no errors at all.

memached.php config file

```
<?php
$config['memcached'] = array(
    'server_1' => array(
        'host' => 'xx.xx.xx.xx',
        'port'        => 11211,
        'weight'    => 1
    )
); 
?>
```

Code being run:

```
$this->load->driver('cache', array('adapter' => 'memcached', 'backup' => 'file'));
$userid = '1';
$key = 'user_products_'.$userid;
$results = $this->cache->memcached->get($key);
if($results == NULL) {
    $qry = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE user_id=$userid");
    $results = $qry->result_array();
    $this->cache->memcached->save($key,$results,'60');
}
```

I have tried both:

```
$this->cache->get();
$this->cache->save();
```

and

```
$this->cache->memcached->get();
$this->cache->memcached->save();
```

In the Memcached Driver file, on line 51, when i use var_dump to check out the output of the get request

```
$data = $this->_memcached->get($id);
var_dump($data);
```

i get:

```
bool(false)
```

Comment: I'm sure `memcahed` class doesn't connect until it is required to do (on first operation). So just perform some read like `$memcache->get('foo');`

Comment: Thanks zerkms, i can now see the connection, and i can see the data being set using $memcache->set('mykey','mydata',60); However im trying to get it working via codeigniter, now that i know the memcached module IS working, i am now not getting any errors when connecting via codeigniter, i cant set or get any values, and nothing shows up on the memcached server. Im trying to SET data using $this->cache->memcached->save($key,$results,'60'); and having no luck what so ever.

Comment: I don't know anything about CI, but without any further details there is nothing to discuss

Comment: what further details do you need?

Comment: I don't know - just update your question with new details - there is nothing about CI there. Put all the code, configs and other things

Comment: yep, seen that but I don't work with CI so cannot say anything

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a problem with the memcached driver in Codeigniter.

I found the following post on the Codeigniter forums. This memcached library worked for me perfectly first time ,with absolutely no issues.  It isn't a solution, as I would prefer to use the built in Codeigniter Cache library, but for the meantime this offers a practical enough work around.

http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/212893/